# Directory / File Monitoring on Windows Server

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Would anyone happen to know of an application / project that is able to monitor a series of directories on a web server.

We currently develop sites using Coldfusion 10, and would like a method or script or even application that actively monitors websites for any modifications to any files and automatically notifies administrators of any time someone or something has made an alteration to a file.

If Coldfusion is possible for this, that would be even better and any advice on how to to monitor directories would also be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example of a directory watcher gateway in the docs: "[Using the example event gateways and gateway applications](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+the+example+event+gateways+and+gateway+applications#Usingtheexampleeventgatewaysandgatewayapplications-DirectoryWatcherGateway)".

Google about for issues people have had with it though. before diving in.